# react component lifecycle componentWillRecieveProps

Tags: reactjs

I am working on an application and when i had the ...this.state in my componentWillRecieveProps my code was not working correctly.

I am not 100% sure why this was affecting my state. Is it because i am always appending the current state when theres no need to do that.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   // this.setState({ ...this.state, ...nextProps })
    this.setState({...nextProps})
  }
```

Comment: You should describe what "not working correctly" means. In any case doing a `setState` here is misguided: you have direct access to the props anyway (`this.props`) so there is no need to complicate things further. `componentWillReceiveProps()` is to determine whether or not a re-render is required based on an examination of `this.props` and `nextProps`.

Answer (score 0):

The [componentWillReceiveProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) lifecycle function is deprecated. Please use the [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) static method instead. In your case it will look like this:

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  state = {
    ...
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {
    return {...nextProps}
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

However in real life it is aimless to convert every props to state without using any logic. In this case it is better to reach the props directly via `this.props`.